# How to deploy Sveltkit app on App Engine?

Tags: deployment, gcloud, svelte

I'm trying to deploy the Sveltkit App on App Engine. Tried several ways but there's not a single efficient way I've found yet.
How to deploy it properly?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a little late for the OP, but for others.

I used this adapter for deploying a svelte app to appengine : https://github.com/HalfdanJ/svelte-adapter-appengine . It worked great.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of ways to deploy. Never used app engine personally, but if you use [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) and the [Node adapter](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node), you should be able to deploy the site like a [normal NodeJS app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app).

Currently, I am using SvelteKit's static adapter and deploying to Firebase just like any other static website. Highly recommend using SvelteKit for building, takes out the complexity of doing it all yourself.